# Rails - fixing hidden google maps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to incorporate google maps into my rails app. Currently my s are returning blank space on my site without maps. How do I get them to return actual maps?

application.css

```
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery-ui/vader
 *= require_tree .
```

events_new.html.erb

```
 <h1>Create New Event</h1>
 <div id="events_map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
 <%= render 'form' %>
 <%= link_to 'Back', events_path %>
```

app/assets/javascript/googlemaps.js

```
 var map, marker, current_pos, initial_pos = new google.maps.LatLng(49.2649, -123.2351);
 function updatePositionDisplay( latlng ) // updates the readout under the map with the supplied position
 {
     document.getElementById('event_latitude').value  = latlng.lat();
     document.getElementById('event_longitude').value = latlng.lng();
 }
 function initializemap()
 {
     var mapOptions = { zoom: 14, center: initial_pos, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
     if (document.getElementById('events_map'))
    { alert( 'There is a map')}
     else {alert('There is no map')}
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('events_map'), mapOptions);
     if (map != null) {alert('Map object has been created')}
     updatePositionDisplay( initial_pos );
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializemap);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you use a gem? https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

Comment: "Use a gem" is a not a actual answer to the problem.